# Could not bind listening IPv4 socket

Tags: ftp, fedora

i did all the steps as shown in the INSTALL file of vsftpd .
 and finally ran this command

/usr/local/sbin/vsftpd &

i got this error :

[root@localhost vsftpd-2.0.5]# 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

please help

Answer (score 3):

Ok it is done .
I added a line at the the end of vsftpd.conf file:

`# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.`
`pam_service_name=vsftpd`[1]

it is working now.

[1]: ***Aside***: *The "`#`" line is a comment, and optional, but it's generally good practice to have them in case you need to refer back*

Answer (score 1):

### You are getting this error probably because of xinetd ftp is running.

**The procedure mentioned below will resolve the following errors:**

- **vsftpd Error** : 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket
- **Ncftpget Error** : Server hangup immediately after connect, for ncftpget

**Follow the procedure mentioned below to rectify the error:**

**A) To View which ftp service is running use**

```
$ lsof -i | grep ftp (Become root and run this command)
```

**B) To stop xinetd :**

```
$ sudo service xinetd stop
```

**C) After stoping xinetd restart your vsftpd service by typing :**

```
$ /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart  (Become root and run this command)
```

**D) Also check the vsftpd.conf with this one**

```
listen=YES

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```